# Passing class back to controller from razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, controller

I have the following code in my razor view that works fine.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><a=href="~/Home/LawFirmDetails?myInfo=@info.CurrentPageIndex&sortField=@info.SortField" class="header">First Name</a></th>

My Contoller signature looks like this:
public async Task<IActionResult> LawFirmDetails(int? page, string sortField)
```

So far, so good, everything works. When I click on the column header it calls LawFirmDetails and passes back the values. In this case, @info is a class and
I am passing back a few values from it. What I really want to do is pass back the whole class though, but when I try to do that it comes back null.

In this case i change the signature to:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LawFirmDetails(Lawyer lawyer) and the href to:
<a=href="~/Home/LawFirmDetails?lawyer=@info" class=header>First Name</a></th>
```

Aside from the fact that I'm now trying to pass back a class rather than a few values I don't think anything is different. Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Just wondered why you need to pass back the entire class - you could just  pass back the Lawyer `Id` in the link then use controller logic to look up the corresponding record in `LawFirmDetails`

Comment: What would be the point of passing back the original unchanged model that the server sent to the view

Comment: I was creating my own pager and sort routines so I was trying to use that to save state. In any event, I can live with returning individual values like those shown here. It works well enough.

Comment: As an aside, you can pass back the whole model with a form post, but not with a href.